# Reusing DbContext in Generic Repository

Tags: c#, generics, frameworks, repository, entity

I am implementing the Repository Pattern with Entity Framework 5.0 - at least i think i am :). This is what i am using

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<C, T> :
 IGenericRepository<T>
    where T : class
    where C : DbContext, new()
{
    private bool disposed = false;
    private C _entities = new C();
    protected C Context
    {
        get { return _entities; }
        set { _entities = value; }
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
        return query;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        return query;
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _entities.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Edit(T entity)
    {
        _entities.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual bool Save()
    {
        return (_entities.SaveChanges() > 0);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
            if (disposing)
                _entities.Dispose();

        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Afterwards this class is inherited by specific repository class - let's say PlaceRepository

```
public class PlaceRepository : GenericRepository<DbEntities, Place>, IPlaceRepository
{ }
```

In another layer (business layer) i am creating instances of the PlaceRepository class - in class called PlaceController. This class has specific methods for the PlaceEntity (CRUD). In this PlaceController i have one method that is used for inserting Place entity in the database, but at the same time i am inserting something in another table (let's say Country table). For CRUD operations over the Country table i have another Repository called CountryRepository.

To sum up, my method in the Place Controller creates instances of two different repositories, to use their methods, thereby creating two different contexts of DbContext. See code below

```
public class PlaceController 
{ 
   public bool InsertPlace(Place toInsert)
   {
      PlaceRepository _placeRepo = new PlaceRepository();
      _placeRepo.Add(toInsert);

      Country _country = new Country();

      _country.Name = "default";

      CountryRepository _countryRepo = new CountryRepository();

      _countryRepo.Add(_country);

     //now i must call save on bothRepositories
     _countryRepo.Save(); _placeRepo.Save();

}
}
```

I need an opinion for this scenario. Is it good to create 2 instances of the context class to make two insertions? If it isn't should i consider using/implementing another pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use IoC(DI) containers for that. That will help you to use 1 instance of the context whole a long the project. You can look also to the way of serviceLocator pattern but I would recoment to use IoC(DI) container. I like Castle.Windsor(the realization of DI pattern) also you can look to Ninject.

Comment: (1) Does this means that my business layer class has to inject the repositories with an instance of the context (let's say constructor injection). And then I should forward the context down to the generic repository (Without Ninject and others)

(2) Another question. What if my top most layer is WCF and i have tight references as like this WCF -> BusinessLayer -> DataLayer. I cannot create context instance in the WCF to pass it down to the business layer. Does this mean that i cannot use two or more business layer controllers with one injected context?

Comment: It all depends on realization. But I expect that you should:

Comment: It all depends on realization. But I expect:
(1) Here it's on your choise. But Castle.Windsor can replace any public property with the class independently where he is. In your pressentation layer you just call:   var service = Infrastructure.Container.Resolve<PlaceService>(); and he will replace all the chain classes public properties with the known types. (2)You can use as much diferent business layer as you want. )

Comment: If you interested in this topic you can write to me directly, I will try to help. It's hard to explain all about relations injection in the few words.

Comment: I've forgot - PlaceRepository _placeRepo = new PlaceRepository(); should be a public property of PlaceController, so it will be also injected with DI container. ;) Thats how you will get any amount of business layers as you want.